# What's the difference between "almost" and "near" when talking about time?

Tags: adverbs

It's **almost** 12 o'clock.

It's **near** 12 o'clock.

There must be a little difference, but how different they are?

Comment: nearly none at all....

Comment: What do you mean?(nearly none at all)

Comment: See the answer below, "nearly" is an adverb, and means "almost" and "very close to"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cookie Monster says, *it's **near** 12 o'clock,* is not idiomatic, but I'm not sure that if I heard it, I would interpret as being exactly the same as *it's **almost** 12 o'clock.*  To me, it almost sounds closer to *it's **around** 12 o'clock*, which actually has a different meaning than the "almost" version.

What's the difference?  There are three possible situations you could be describing when you say that the time is close to 12 o'clock:

1. **The time is a few minutes before twelve, but definitely not twelve yet.**

This is what the **almost** version means.  Different ways of saying this include:

> It's almost 12 o'clock.
>
> It's nearly 12 o'clock.
>
> It's just before 12 o'clock.
>
> It's a few minutes shy of 12 o'clock.

2. **The time is close to twelve, but it could be either before or after twelve.**

This is the **about** version:

> It's about 12 o'clock.
>
> It's around 12 o'clock.
>
> It's 12 o'clock, give or take [a few minutes].

To me, this is what I'd assume someone who said "near 12" would mean, I guess because I'm interpreting *near* as being an exact synonym of *around*, rather than being the same meaning as *nearly*.

3. **The time is a few minutes after twelve.**

There are fewer ways of saying this:

> It's just after 12 o'clock.

In BrE, you could say:

> It's just gone twelve.

But many AmE speakers would not understand that version.

Answer (score 1):

*It's near 12 o'clock* is not very idiomatic English (something that's not natural to say in this particular context). I would even go so far as to suggest that it's probably not grammatically valid English either, but who knows. You should say instead:

> It's nearly 12 o'clock.

And it basically means exactly the same thing as *It's almost 12 o'clock*. I'm really failing to see any difference in meaning. So, you can very much use these two phrases interchangeably. And they're both used with more or less equal frequency.

Comment: Because I am not an American speaker, I don't feel comfortable saying "near 12 o'clock" is not idiomatic, Americans tell the time differently from British English speakers, but "nearly" is acceptable/correct in both dialects.